# Selenium Webdriver - how to cache only exact value from getText()

Tags: java, string, selenium, gettext

In my `@Test` have a line like:

`String newPassword =getDriver().findElement(By.id("somethin")).getText();`

which returns for example text like: 
*Password for testuser changed to: v5ZqppuBycjZ*

How to take just the last piece of notification ? 
How to exclude from getText() only last 12 characters (with new pass in that case) ?

Comment: I think "somethin" is a text box that containing new password correct ? If no then use id of your text box to get value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [split method of String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) like this:

```
String p[] = getDriver().findElement(By.id("somethin")).getText().split(" ");
String newPassword = p[p.length-1];
```

The above code will fetch the text and split them using space(" ") as the separator and put them in a string array. Then, we can just fetch the last item in the array, which is the text, concerned.

Comment: Realized that substring could be easier :)       Solved by: `getText().substring(42, 54);`

Comment: okay.. :) but, then again in case the text changes and say texts "changed to" are removed from the returned output, you will be in trouble.. ;)

Comment: What Subh said... you don't want to use substring() like you did. What if the user name changes length? What if the password changes length? Your test will fail incorrectly.